# How to https link which are registered with self signed certificate in android?

Tags: android, ssl

I want to open a link in android browser. I have used below code. It is working fine as expected.

```
Intent updateIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,
Uri.parse("http://www.example.com");
context.startActivity(updateIntent);
```

but when I open https url in android chrome browser it is saying private connection error in browser. The problem is web server is registered with self-signed certificate. I think the problem is of certificate because certificate is not included In android chrome browser because the certificate is self signed. How can I open link in android browser that is self-signed.

Comment: So do one thing replace the value https to http like this String value = "http://www.example.com";
  value.replace("https", "http");

Comment: it will have one problem because the server is not bound with http because  the requirement is no webservice should be called with http protocol

Comment: yes i also had faced the same problem while parsing some data from a json api so i had replced the http to https then that works fine for me..

Comment: it could have been better option for me as well if server was bound with http :(

Answer (score 0):

So do one thing replace the value https to http like this

```
String value = "http://www.example.com";        
Intent updateIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,
Uri.parse(value.replace("https", "http"));
context.startActivity(updateIntent);
```

Then it will work...Hopeit will help you

Comment: It will work but the problem is server is not bound with http binding it is only bound with https request. This is the requirement no webservice should be entertained that is not https